# Is the spectrum of a product of two operators, $AB$, invariant under $UAU^{\dagger}$ for unitary $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics

This question is about linear operators on a Hilbert space. If necessary, the Hilbert space can be assumed to be finite dimensional. I have two Hermitian operators, $A$ and $B$. Do we have

$$
\sigma(AB) = \sigma(UAU^{\dagger}B), 
$$

for a unitary $U$? $\sigma(X)$ denotes the spectrum of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not generally the case.

**Finite dimensional counter-example:**
$$
\{0,1\} = 
\sigma\left[\pmatrix{0&1\\0&1} \right] =\sigma\left[\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \right] \neq\\
\sigma\left[\pmatrix{0&0\\0&2}\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \right]
=\sigma\left[\pmatrix{0&0\\0&2} \right] = \{0,2\}
$$
Note in particular that
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1} = U\pmatrix{0&0\\0&2}U^*
$$
with $U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&1}$